# How can I get element by the Index from the OrderedTable in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

Nim has `OrderedTable` how can I get the element by its index, and not by its key?

If it's possible - is this an efficient operation, like `O(log n)` or better?

```
import tables
let map = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}.toOrderedTable
```

Something like

```
map.getByIndex(1) # No such method
```

P.S.

I'm currently using both `seq` and `Table` to provide both key and indexed access and wonder if it could be replaced by `OrderedTable`

```
type IndexedMap = ref object
  list*: seq[float]
  map*:  Table[string, float]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct index access to ordered tables because of their internal structure. The typical way to access the elements in order is:

```
import tables

let map = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}.toOrderedTable

for f in map.keys:
  echo $f
```

Basically, accessing the [keys iterator](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tables.html#keys.i%2COrderedTable%5BA%2CB%5D). If you click through the *source* link in the documentation, you reach [the actual iterator code](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/version-1-2/lib/pure/collections/tables.nim#L1719):

```
  let L = len(t)
  forAllOrderedPairs:
    yield t.data[h].key
```

And if you follow [the implementation of the forAllOrderedPairs template](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/version-1-2/lib/pure/collections/tables.nim#L1253) (it's recommended you are using an editor with *jump to implementation* capabilities to inspect such code easier):

```
  if t.counter > 0:
    var h = t.first
    while h >= 0:
      var nxt = t.data[h].next
      if isFilled(t.data[h].hcode):
        yieldStmt
      h = nxt
```

No idea about performance there, but it won't be as fast as accessing a simple list/array, because the internal structure of `OrderedTable` contains a hidden `data` field with the actual keys and values, and it requires an extra conditional check to verify that the entry is actually being used. This implementation detail is probably a compromise to avoid reshuffling the whole list after a single item deletion.

If your accesses are infrequent, using the iterator to find the value might be enough. If benchmarking shows it's a bottleneck you could try *freezing* the keys/values iterator into a local list and use that instead, as long as you don't want to mutate further the `OrderedTable`.

Or return to your original idea of keeping a separate list.